# how to retrieve user session attributes like username?

Tags: java, servlets

Hello, I want to get the username from session after the user logged in and store in my database when I'm using insert or update.

When the user is logged in, I setAttribute like this

```
 try
 {      
     LoginBean user = new LoginBean();
     user.setUserName(request.getParameter("username"));
     user.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

     user = DAO.login(user);

     if (user.isValid())
     {
          HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);       
          session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",user); 
          response.sendRedirect("/oosd/login/member.jsp"); //logged-in page             
     }
     else 
          response.sendRedirect("/oosd/login/invalidLogin.jsp"); //error page 
}
```

How do I retrieve the username later on other servlets as a string for inserting ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`HttpSession#getAttribute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) with the same attribute name to reobtain the set attribute.

```
LoginBean user = (LoginBean) session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser");

if (user != null) {
    String userName = user.getUserName();
    // ...
}
```